# Context Menu is not working in flash player 10.1

Tags: apache-flex, flex3, flexbuilder

I write a flex application. I added some custom menu items in context menu. when I compiled this code using flashplayer 10.0, it works fine and my added context menu items are shown when I Right-Click. But when I compile same code for flashPlayer 10.1, menu items that I added in context menu are not shown when I Right-Click. What should I do to resolve this issue?
I am using sdk 3.5.

Any help or suggestion will be appreciated.

I am doing this;

```
    private var cm:ContextMenu = new ContextMenu();        
    var versionMenu:ContextMenuItem = null;
    var dateMenu:ContextMenuItem = null;
    if(model.appVersion.length > 0)
    {
      versionMenu = new ContextMenuItem(model.appVersion);
    }
    if(model.releaseDate.length > 0)
    {
      dateMenu = new ContextMenuItem(model.releaseDate);
    }

     cm.hideBuiltInItems();
     var cmArray:Array = new Array();
     if(versionMenu != null)
       cmArray.push(versionMenu);
     if(dateMenu != null)
       cmArray.push(dateMenu);
     cm.customItems = cmArray;
```

Thanks.

Comment: Do you use AIR on Flash Player? In AIR context menu items can not be reused.

Comment: its a flex application. it is working fine when I use flashplayer 10.0 but it does not work when I use flashplayer 10.1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there is no reason. It works fine for me in flashPlayer 10.1 . Also it is listed as supported in 10.1 here : http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/ui/ContextMenu.html

alert the isSupported property in code to double check (it will most definitely be true).

Comment: I am willing to bet that if you place a breakpoint on <code>versionMenu = new ContextMenuItem(model.appVersion);</code> or <code>dateMenu = new ContextMenuItem(model.releaseDate);</code> they will not be hit. Remove the if statements and set these directly.

Comment: @ Basarat Ali: I put alerts inside both ifs. they are hit and alerts are shown. but the entries in contextMenu not shown.

Comment: I assume you have added the context menu to some item on the stage using either : contextMenu="{cm}" binding.  OR setting the contextMenu property of some item on stage in code.

Comment: I am doing this in application tag. contextMenu="{cm}". and yes this contextMenu is bindable. Is there wrong something with this? how can I make it to work?

Comment: you are doing what? a simple <code>this;</code> is not useful at all

Comment: instead of private var cm:ContextMenu = new ContextMenu(); try <code>public var cm:ContextMenu = new ContextMenu();</code>

Comment: I did try but its not working. I think I am missing something in configuration while compiling with flashplayer 10.1. because the default was 10.0.

Comment: an example is provided here: http://blog.flexexamples.com/2007/08/20/using-a-custom-context-menu-with-the-flex-datagrid-control/   I also tried this but its not working.

Comment: that example it works on my computer :( I cannot help with what I cannot recreate

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to create a context menu for `Application` then here is the correct code:

```
<s:Application ... initialize="init();">

    private function init():void
    {
        var versionItem:ContextMenuItem = new ContextMenuItem("Version 1.5.443");
        contextMenu.hideBuiltInItems();
        contextMenu.customItems = [ versionItem ];
    }

</s:Application>
```